# Identifying App Dependencies in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

One of the GKE cluster is used a shared cluster and hosts multiple line of business applications.

These line of business apps, written in different languages (C#, go, ruby, java),

- Interact with each other (but don't use mesh technology). Example: App1 gives a REST API call to APIs hosted in App2 (in different namespace)
- Interact with other PaaS services in Google Cloud. Example, App1 interacts with Cache, DNS, and PostgreSQL; whereas App2 hosts data in MongoDB Atlas and leverages Redis Cache

One of the ways to identify dependencies of each app is to look at `ConfigMap` or `Helm Charts` (apart from `application configuration`) to identify external app/service dependencies. This will be time taking exercise.

**Is there any tool that can help discover these app dependencies in an automated way?**

Answer (score 0):

What kind of dependencies do you exactly mean ? Kubernetes doesn't care about the content of the containers it runs or their codebase or their logic. It works as a container orchestrator only. It's a job for CI/CD process to take care about dependencies or package manager, like **helm**.

Kubernetes may provide some features, like [`initContainers`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) that would check availability of the certain service in the cluster before starting another one, dependant on them, but it's up to the administrator or app developer to design them.

Comment: I want to identify app dependencies (like, databases, redis, etc.) running within the cluster